# How do we use select inside an expanded collection on Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Following query in [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) displays signed-in user's profile and its manager `Diego Siciliani`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager
```

But you may notice in the response it is returning tons of attributes of `manager` object, as well. Some of these attributes are objects (such as `assignedPlans`) themselves and have their own attributes, as well.

**Question**: How can we filter the above query so it returns user profile (that it is already doing) along with `ONLY` the following attirbute value the user's manager: `"displayName": "Diego Siciliani"`

**Remark**: Following query returns the error shown below: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($select=displayName)`

> Invalid $select properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the below query to get user and his manager details

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id,displayName)&$select=id,displayName&$count=true

ConsistencyLevel eventual
```

[image]

**Update** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=displayName)&$count=true`

[image]

Comment: I am getting the error: `Resource 'userid' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.` Also, there may have been misunderstanding on the question. Please note that the we want displaying all the attributes of user profile, `BUT` for user's manager we want only the `displayName` of the manager (that would be `Diego Siciliani`)

Comment: Please make sure to pass the user id in the first request and also I have updated my answer according to you is a requirement. if you are specifically looking to remove odata.type and odata.id from the mangers list it is not possible.

Comment: @ SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity Your suggestion worked. But it works only when you login to the Graph Explorer. It does not work with the default user (Megan Brown) for the Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

It is known issue from Microsoft that nested $select combined with $expand doesn't work (i.e. $expand=some_path($select=some_field) does not work with Microsoft Graph API).

See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#query-parameter-limitations

```
$expand:
No support for nextLink
No support for more than 1 level of expand
No support with extra parameters ($filter, $select)
```

I wish they would implement it because right now we either have to pull a lot of extra data (e.g. for managers), or we have to make a lot of requests per user to retrieve just the field we want.

There's a solution that deal with batch requesting but it requires a json solution:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: The `$select` seems to work, as seen in the screenshots above which I've also successfully tested.
But there's another limitation to the $expand query parameter in the docs:
`Returns a maximum of 20 objects.` 
This really makes it useless - at least for getting all group memberships of a user in this one query.

Comment: And as there is no support for `nextLink` you don't even know that there are more elements. You can only gess, that if you get 20 items, there might be more.